# Open iOS application from universal links

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I have implemented universal links in my application by uploading "apple-app-site-association" to my server and enabling "associated domains" in my project(by adding applinks). My app opens whenever I click on my server weblink from Safari browser.

1) Its not working on any other browser
2) I need to open my app from other apps as well, i.e. Instagram, Twitter etc.

How can I achieve the above scenarios using universal links. If not, is there any other way of achieving the same.

Comment: Have you tried looking into using Firebase Dynamic Links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all apps will open universal links in you app. You can read a little more here:

"Pasting a Universal Link directly into the Safari URL field doesn’t cause the app to open automatically. If you do this, you will have to manually pull the website down so that a prompt will appear at the top asking you to open the respective app.
But, if you paste links in Facebook(app), Twitter(app), Mail(app) or even if you go to Facebook on Safari and then click on a universal link, the app opens directly.
Universal links will not works for all the apps in iOS. If you click on a universal link from any of the “BLACK LISTED” apps, it will not open the app. Go to this link to know more.
As in step one, for the first time you will have to manually pull down the website and click “open” to open the link using the respective app. The iOS will “remember” to open the app instead of opening the safari if the universal link with the registered domains are clicked."

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/universal-links/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links