# iOS: Universal links only work from Safari

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

When user completes the registration form in my app I send him an email with link to confirm his registration. When he taps the link he should be redirected to my app. But this only works when I open gmail in Safari. When I go trough the Gmail app it opens the link inside gmail in some WKWebView and the built in mail app opens it in Safari. This is my apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "4DD4JT5DY34.com.edgepatrick.pinkpenguin",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- I tested my apple-app-site-association file with [AASA Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) and it show that **everything is valid**
- When I visit my website it **shows the smart banner** and it **launches my app correctly**.

However, if I try to open the link in any email app it opens in Safari/inside the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was this:

I'm using SendGrid to send the verification email, the link in the mail looks like this `https://auth.pinkpenguin.tech/nmc/j25OP~~Eg` but in reality the url points to some SendGrid url `https://u1953582.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=LQJuwSFztYcP....` which then redirects to my pinkpenguin link, **when I removed that redirect it works fine from both Gmail and default Mail apps.**

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479741/open-ios-application-from-universal-links?rq=1) is a similar question, may help someone.